# Cannot install xcb package

Tags: debian, upgrade, software-updates

I tried `sudo -f remove` and even `autoclean` but my new packages and updates aren't getting downloaded.

```
admin@pop-os:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  avahi-utils lib32gcc-s1 lib32stdc++6 libasn1-8-heimdal libc6-i386
  libclang-common-6.0-dev libclang-common-7-dev libclang1-6.0 libclang1-7
  libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl1:i386 libfprint-2-tod1 libgbm1:i386 libgc1c2
  libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal libllvm6.0
  libllvm7 libnvidia-common-440-server libnvidia-decode-440-server
  libnvidia-encode-440-server libnvidia-extra-440-server
  libnvidia-fbc1-440-server libnvidia-gl-440-server libnvidia-glcore
  libnvidia-ifr1-440-server libomp-10-dev libomp-dev libomp5-10
  libroken18-heimdal libwayland-server0:i386 libwind0-heimdal
  libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxnvctrl0 llvm-6.0 llvm-6.0-dev llvm-6.0-runtime
  llvm-7 llvm-7-dev llvm-7-runtime nvidia-compute-utils-440-server
  nvidia-dkms-440-server nvidia-kernel-common-440-server
  nvidia-kernel-source-440-server nvidia-settings nvidia-support
  nvidia-utils-440-server screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libxcb-xfixes0:i386

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libxcb-xfixes0:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1171 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/105 kB of archives.
After this operation, 148 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 315734 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxcb-xfixes0_1.14-2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libxcb-xfixes0:i386 (1.14-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libxcb-xfixes0_1.14-2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libxcb-xfixes0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libxcb-xfixes0:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libxcb-xfixes0_1.14-2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: This link may provide some answers: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-broken-packages-ubuntu/. What happens if you run `sudo apt autoremove`?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a mixture of i386 and amd64 packages. I would actually try the opposite

> apt-get remove libxcb-xfixes0:i386

this would probably try to undo the half-install of `libxcb-xfixes0:i386` that it is trying to do. I guess this is an x86-64 system where you already have installed libxcb-xfixes0, and libxcb-xfixes0:i386 and libxcb-xfixes0 are conflicting on '/usr/share/doc/libxcb-xfixes0/changelog.Debian.gz' (perhaps libxcb-xfixes0 is not at the last version?)

If the above doesn't fix it, try listing the package which owns the file where the conflict happens:

> dpkg -S /usr/share/doc/libxcb-xfixes0/changelog.Debian.gz